# Reconnect socket with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, server, socket.io

I need your help regarding reconnecting with nodejs.

Indeed, I am developing a web application that uses socket.io, and I would like to know how to reconnect the player to the same socket when there is a disconnection either from the network or from the server.

I can't post my code here, but this code is very similar to mine :

```
//When a connection to server is made from client
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    
    //When host connects for the first time
    socket.on('host-join', (data) =>{
        
        //Check to see if id passed in url corresponds to id of kahoot game in database
        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var dbo = db.db("kahootDB");
            var query = { id:  parseInt(data.id)};
            dbo.collection('kahootGames').find(query).toArray(function(err, result){
                if(err) throw err;
                
                //A kahoot was found with the id passed in url
                if(result[0] !== undefined){
                    var gamePin = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000; //new pin for game

                    games.addGame(gamePin, socket.id, false, {playersAnswered: 0, questionLive: false, gameid: data.id, question: 1}); //Creates a game with pin and host id

                    var game = games.getGame(socket.id); //Gets the game data

                    socket.join(game.pin);//The host is joining a room based on the pin

                    console.log('Game Created with pin:', game.pin); 

                    //Sending game pin to host so they can display it for players to join
                    socket.emit('showGamePin', {
                        pin: game.pin
                    });
                }else{
                    socket.emit('noGameFound');
                }
                db.close();
            });
        });
        
    });
    
    //When the host connects from the game view
    socket.on('host-join-game', (data) => {
        var oldHostId = data.id;
        var game = games.getGame(oldHostId);//Gets game with old host id
        if(game){
            game.hostId = socket.id;//Changes the game host id to new host id
            socket.join(game.pin);
            var playerData = players.getPlayers(oldHostId);//Gets player in game
            for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(players.players).length; i++){
                if(players.players[i].hostId == oldHostId){
                    players.players[i].hostId = socket.id;
                }
            }
            var gameid = game.gameData['gameid'];
            MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
                if (err) throw err;
    
                var dbo = db.db('kahootDB');
                var query = { id:  parseInt(gameid)};
                dbo.collection("kahootGames").find(query).toArray(function(err, res) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    
                    var question = res[0].questions[0].question;
                    var answer1 = res[0].questions[0].answers[0];
                    var answer2 = res[0].questions[0].answers[1];
                    var answer3 = res[0].questions[0].answers[2];
                    var answer4 = res[0].questions[0].answers[3];
                    var correctAnswer = res[0].questions[0].correct;
                    
                    socket.emit('gameQuestions', {
                        q1: question,
                        a1: answer1,
                        a2: answer2,
                        a3: answer3,
                        a4: answer4,
                        correct: correctAnswer,
                        playersInGame: playerData.length
                    });
                    db.close();
                });
            });
            
            
            io.to(game.pin).emit('gameStartedPlayer');
            game.gameData.questionLive = true;
        }else{
            socket.emit('noGameFound');//No game was found, redirect user
        }
    });
    
    //When player connects for the first time
    socket.on('player-join', (params) => {
        
        var gameFound = false; //If a game is found with pin provided by player
        
        //For each game in the Games class
        for(var i = 0; i < games.games.length; i++){
            //If the pin is equal to one of the game's pin
            if(params.pin == games.games[i].pin){
                
                console.log('Player connected to game');
                
                var hostId = games.games[i].hostId; //Get the id of host of game
                
                
                players.addPlayer(hostId, socket.id, params.name, {score: 0, answer: 0}); //add player to game
                
                socket.join(params.pin); //Player is joining room based on pin
                
                var playersInGame = players.getPlayers(hostId); //Getting all players in game
                
                io.to(params.pin).emit('updatePlayerLobby', playersInGame);//Sending host player data to display
                gameFound = true; //Game has been found
            }
        }
        
        //If the game has not been found
        if(gameFound == false){
            socket.emit('noGameFound'); //Player is sent back to 'join' page because game was not found with pin
        }
        
        
    });
    
    //When the player connects from game view
    socket.on('player-join-game', (data) => {
        var player = players.getPlayer(data.id);
        if(player){
            var game = games.getGame(player.hostId);
            socket.join(game.pin);
            player.playerId = socket.id;//Update player id with socket id
            
            var playerData = players.getPlayers(game.hostId);
            socket.emit('playerGameData', playerData);
        }else{
            socket.emit('noGameFound');//No player found
        }
        
    });
    
    //When a host or player leaves the site
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        var game = games.getGame(socket.id); //Finding game with socket.id
        //If a game hosted by that id is found, the socket disconnected is a host
        if(game){
            //Checking to see if host was disconnected or was sent to game view
            if(game.gameLive == false){
                games.removeGame(socket.id);//Remove the game from games class
                console.log('Game ended with pin:', game.pin);

                var playersToRemove = players.getPlayers(game.hostId); //Getting all players in the game

                //For each player in the game
                for(var i = 0; i < playersToRemove.length; i++){
                    players.removePlayer(playersToRemove[i].playerId); //Removing each player from player class
                }

                io.to(game.pin).emit('hostDisconnect'); //Send player back to 'join' screen
                socket.leave(game.pin); //Socket is leaving room
            }
        }else{
            //No game has been found, so it is a player socket that has disconnected
            var player = players.getPlayer(socket.id); //Getting player with socket.id
            //If a player has been found with that id
            if(player){
                var hostId = player.hostId;//Gets id of host of the game
                var game = games.getGame(hostId);//Gets game data with hostId
                var pin = game.pin;//Gets the pin of the game
                
                if(game.gameLive == false){
                    players.removePlayer(socket.id);//Removes player from players class
                    var playersInGame = players.getPlayers(hostId);//Gets remaining players in game

                    io.to(pin).emit('updatePlayerLobby', playersInGame);//Sends data to host to update screen
                    socket.leave(pin); //Player is leaving the room
            
                }
            }
        }
        
    });
```

And so with this code, how could I implement a reconnect solution.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could give each player an ID onconnect (which is not the socket id). You save this ID in an array/object (server and / or client-side) and if he disconnects you keep him in the party/session. If he reconnects you put him in again.

Comment: Thanks Krani for your answer. But I think that the problem is the same because when the client lose the connection, he's kicked from the server and so, if he reconnects he will change the custom player ID.. isn't it ?

Comment: 1. Create an ID on the client side  2. Save the ID client side local or session storge  3. On connect with the websocket send the id  4. Connect the socket.id and the ID on serverside (with an array or Object)  5. Every time someone connects check if his id is an party and place him in again

Comment: Thanks Krani, i understand. Last thing, how to make a difference between a client who really want to close the connection and a client who has a disconnection with his network ?

Comment: Ok i think this one is out of my socket knowledge but i think you can never really make a difference. But maybe you can use the disconnect message. If you get a disconnect message he wants to and if you dont get one its a loss. Then the front end needs to disconnect onclose aswell.